# SQL Server 2008 Reporting Services Throwing Error

Tags: sql-server

I am getting the following error ( which it was working fine previously )

**An error has occurred during report processing. (rsProcessingAborted)
The execution failed for the shared data set 'CombinedStatsPerClient'. (rsDataSetExecutionError)
Cannot create a connection to data source ' Data source for shared dataset'. (rsErrorOpeningConnection)
For more information about this error navigate to the report server on the local server machine, or enable remote errors**

What can be the issue, Connection..or

Answer (score 0):

The Problem was with the database connection string which is sorted

Answer (score -2):

From reading the error:

Cannot create a connection to data source ' Data source for shared dataset'.

Sounds like there is something wrong with either your connection, or the connection you have set up for your report.

Comment: I tried connecting to the DATABASE ( using same connection string ) directly using SQL SERVER it works great, not sure what is the problem

Comment: When you upload your report to the report server, you specify which shared data connection to use - you may want to check this.